# PL/SQL, CASE statement or if statement

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am new to PL/SQL

I have a code like this

```
SELECT f.code,f.date,f.amt, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY f.code ORDER BY f.date DESC) ranki
FROM advance.alloc f
```

and shows

```
 CODE   DATE      AMT ranki
    122 12/31/2016 3   1
    122 12/31/2015 7   2
    122 12/31/2014 3   3
    123  6/30/2015 3   1
    125  6/30/2015 2   1
    125 12/31/2014 8   2
```

Logic is this

```
if DATE = 12/__/__  AND ranki = 1 THEN ranki 1, so 122 picks 12/31/2016 3
if DATE = 6/30/__  AND ranki = 1  AND if ranki = 2 exists THEN  then pick the second one,so 125 picks 12/31/2014 8
if 6/30__ and ranki is ONLY 1 shows Blank on date LIKE 123
```

so I would like to show

```
   122 12/31/2016 3 
   123 __________ 3 
   125 12/31/2014 8
```

How can I code like this PL/SQL?

```
WHEN to_char(af.date,'MM') = 12 AND af.ranki = 1 THEN af.date END
```

I could code first logic, but I can not figure out how to code the rest of the logic

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why in PL/SQL? Or do you mean "in Oracle SQL"?  (The solution below uses standard analytic functions, so it is not specific to Oracle.)

Add more information through analytic functions, in addition to `ranki`. Extract the month from the row with `ranki = 1`, and also the total count for each `code`. Then the WHERE clause can follow your logic step by step.

```
with
     f ( code, dt, amount ) as (
       select 122, to_date('12/31/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 3 from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('12/31/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 7 from dual union all
       select 122, to_date('12/31/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 3 from dual union all
       select 123, to_date( '6/30/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 3 from dual union all
       select 125, to_date( '6/30/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 2 from dual union all
       select 125, to_date('12/31/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 8 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated data (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select code, case when mth = 12 or ranki = 2 then dt end as dt, amount
from   ( select code, dt, amount,
                first_value(extract (month from dt)) 
                             over (partition by code order by dt desc) as mth,
                row_number() over (partition by code order by dt desc) as ranki,
                count(*)     over (partition by code)                  as cnt
         from   f
       )
where mth = 12 and ranki = 1
   or cnt =  1
   or mth =  6 and ranki = 2
;

CODE DT         AMOUNT
---- ---------- ------
 122 12/31/2016      3
 123                 3
 125 12/31/2014      8
```